# How to make this codes run.?

Tags: java, string, for-loop

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String sInput1;
    int iInput1, iInput2,iNum,iCards,iNumInCards;
    Random Numbers = new Random();
    int Number[][] = new int[10][4];
    int Cards[] = new int[10];
    int Slots[] = new int[9];

    for (int y=0;y<=9;y++)
    {
        for (int z=0;z<=3;z++)
        {
            iCards = y;
            iNumInCards = z;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        iNum = Numbers.nextInt(10) + 1;
        // yung iNum yung 40 random numbers
    }

    Number[iCards][iNumInCards] = iNum;
    System.out.println (Number[iCards][iNumInCards]);
}
```

I would like to get the iCards and iNumInCards for using them in the 2d array that I created. How do I do it?

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking, but assigning to a variable in a loop (without using previous values, or storing them anywhere) is a bad sign. What do you expect your first loop to achieve? Why would you expect it to be any different to just `iCards = 8; iNumInCards = 2;`? I think you should probably step through the code you've got to understand what's wrong here...

Comment: What means "How to make this codes run.?"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int Number[][] = new int[10][4];
int Cards[] = new int[10];
int Slots[] = new int[9];

for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
{
    for (int z = 0; z < 4; z++)
    {
        iCards = y;
        iNumInCards = z;
        iNum = Numbers.nextInt(10) + 1;
        Number[iCards][iNumInCards] = iNum;
    }
}
```

Basically your problem is that

- you don't seem to understand linear program flow and control statements
- I'm not sure you understand arrays
- and I'm not sure you really understand what you're trying to do.

You should probably read about the basics of Java, as such:
   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/

Anyways, the code fragment I posted initializes the 2-dimensional array with random numbers, supposedly the way as you probably originally intended.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what to comment on it, but so far I'm getting null pointers in my head.

Comment: I'm still having a hard time understanding the question :P

Comment: He's trying to initialize the values in the 2D array, but can't figure out how. That's how I interpreted it, anyways. My guess would be that knowing the **very basics of Java** would help with that.

Comment: Wow, this was ridiculously antagonistic of me. Thanks for picking it as an answer after a year and a half; but I shouldn't have been so harsh. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Those `iCards`, `iNumInCards` & `iNum` need to be initialized ( assignment of an initial value). When variable is declared, memory is allocated for the variable. This memory must be initialized to contain some definite value before the variable can be used in an expression.

Pitfall possibility :

`Random` class from `util` package hasn't been imported yet.

Here's the fixed one :

```
public class Testing  {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String sInput1;
    int iInput1, iInput2,iNum = 0,iCards = 0,iNumInCards = 0;
    java.util.Random Numbers = new  java.util.Random();
    int Number[][] = new int[10][4];
    int Cards[] = new int[10];
    int Slots[] = new int[9];

    for (int y=0;y<=9;y++)
    {
        for (int z=0;z<=3;z++)
        {
            iCards = y;
            iNumInCards = z;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        iNum = Numbers.nextInt(10) + 1;
        // yung iNum yung 40 random numbers
    }

    Number[iCards][iNumInCards] = iNum;
    System.out.println (Number[iCards][iNumInCards]);
  }
}
```

Comment: As far as I can see, this will solve the OPs compilation problem...and beyond anything else, seems correct to me...